# Wordpress and Zend Framework

Tags: php, wordpress, zend-framework

I can't get my head around integrating these two in the way I would like to.

I have a wordpress installation running a website. I also include the ZF via a plugin so that I can use the codebase.

However, I would like to also have the ability to utilise Zend Controllers in the same way I do on my normal Zend Applications... for example, I may want a form to submit to a zend controller so I can handle it there.... How can I do this?

I'm just after a little pointer here because I've read all the previous questions on here and none answer my question specifically.

Comment: Wordpress has his own routing (.htaccess) - Zend_Controllers are for Zend Applications, being able to use Zend Parts outside of a Zend Application is great, but certainly not every part is usable as you do within a Zend Application. The following link might help though
http://www.krotscheck.net/2009/05/16/bootstrapping-a-startup-zend-and-wordpress-auth-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this?
http://www.leftjoin.net/2011/03/integrating-zend-framework-with-wordpress/
I'm not sure about this but you would need to use Zend_Controller without the URL structure,
I don't know if that's easy to reroute...